# Many processes writing to a FIFO at the same time

Tags: c, multiprocessing, ipc, fifo

In my application, I have one reader process that will read structs of info from a FIFO and then go to sleep for some amount of time and then read the next, but on the sender side, I have many processes that might send messages simultaneously. All that will be sent is going to be structs.

What I am wondering is: will this cause my data to be mixed up in a way where I wouldn't be able to retrieve data? Is a semaphore enough for synchronization or is it even needed?

Comment: There isn't enough context, but probably yes, you will need a synchronizing primitive to ensure that concurrent writes don't mess up each other.

Comment: What more context is needed?

Comment: How *exactly* are the messages being written?  Post your actual code.

Comment: That sounds like a good use case for unix domain sockets, not fifos.

Comment: [Quote:](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) POSIX.1 says that writes of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be
       atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous
       sequence.  Writes of more than PIPE_BUF bytes may be nonatomic:
       the kernel may interleave the data with data written by other
       processes.  POSIX.1 requires PIPE_BUF to be at least 512 bytes.
       (On Linux, PIPE_BUF is 4096 bytes.)

Comment: @HansPassant It's important to note, though, that applies to individual `write()` calls.  If code uses a higher-level function such as `fprintf()` or `fwrite()` there's no guarantee that any one call to that function will map to any particular number of individual `write()` calls.  10 calls to `fwrite()` might result in just one call to `write()`, while a single call to `fprintf()` may result in 7 `write()` calls, for example.